# SQL - alternative to left outer join

Tags: sql, oracle, odbc, left-join

There is a standard way in SQL to conut a number of rows joined to one table acepting also the 0?
That is one example :

```
SELECT t1.id, COUNT(t2.*)
FROM t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 ON ( t1.id = t2.id )
GROUP BY t1.id
```

I need a alternative because i use odbc with different databases, and on some databases the left join aren't supported.

Comment: May be `SELECT t1.id, (select COUNT(t2.*) where t2.id = t1.id) as t2_count FROM t1` ?

Comment: @ThinkJet you should post it as an answer

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Ok, done. But it's too short for normal answer :)

Comment: Seriously? There are still DBMS that do not support outer joins?

Comment: Oracle materialized views don't support ANSI join syntax ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  t1.id, 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t2 WHERE t2.id = t1.id) as t2_count 
FROM t1
```

Comment: Thx! i try if that is supported on mysql, access, sql server and oracle because are the db that i use.

Answer (score 0):

Two Options:
Option 1: use the (+) operator:

```
SELECT t1.id, COUNT(t2.*)
  FROM t1, t2
 WHERE t2.id(+) = t1.id
 GROUP BY t1.id
```

I don;t know if it works on all drivers. Option 2 that will work with all drivers is to create a view and create the view instead.

Comment: That it's only for oracle